# Swift - Tableview with collectionviewcell not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a tableview that has two types -

call it A - a regular tableviewcell with title/type
call it B - a second tableviewcell that has a collection view of data

All rows that are even (0,2,4,6, etc.) should be A and odd rows should be B

Here is my viewController with basic Tableview Functionality:

```
    //MARK: Struct - create the data type

   
    struct dealType {
    var title: String?
    var type: String?
    }

    //MARK: Variables - define the array with 8 variables

        var dealTypeArray: [dealType] =
       //Venue Specials
       [dealType(title: "Venue Specials", type: "Free Tier"),
       dealType(title: "Venue Specials", type: "Free Tier"),
       //Events
       dealType(title: "Events", type: "Free Tier"),
       dealType(title: "Events", type: "Free Tier"),
       //Liquor Specials
       dealType(title: "Liquor Specials", type: "Free Tier"),
       dealType(title: "Liquor Specials", type: "Free Tier"),
      //Night Life Guides
       dealType(title: "Night Life Guides", type: "Recommended"),
       dealType(title: "Night Life Guides", type: "Recommended")
 ]
     

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    //should return 8 variables
    return dealTypeArray.count
    
   
     } 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
    //(A)
    if indexPath.row.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:       "specialTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! specialTableViewCell
        cell.type = dealTypeArray[indexPath.row].type ?? ""
        cell.title = dealTypeArray[indexPath.row].title ?? ""
        return cell
    //else return B
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SpecialPicTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SpecialPicTableViewCell
        cell.typeSelected = dealTypeArray[indexPath.row].title ?? ""
        return cell
    }
   }
```

Then I define View Did Load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //A uses a Nib, B does need need to registered
    DealsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "specialTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "specialTableViewCell")
    DealsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    DealsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    DealsTableView.dataSource = self
    DealsTableView.delegate = self
    self.DealsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Please include more info, e.g. how is your dealTypeArray created.

Comment: ... and what actually happens.  eg.are the B cells completely missing? Or are they present but poorly configured?  Or do  they become A cells.